# XSD element with one xml child and then content (including html/xml)

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an xml document that contains some html.

```
<begin-line>
    <verse-num>6</verse-num>a mixed people<footnote id="f2">
        Or <i>a foreign people</i>; Hebrew <i>a bastard</i>
    </footnote> shall dwell in Ashdod,
</begin-line>
```

The verse-num element is the only element I wan't validated, the rest I want valideted to one large group of a string type, which can hold html, and also sometimes some more xml (like footnote).

Here is the schema I have right now which doesn't do the trick.

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="begin-line">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="verse-num">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:unsignedByte">
                                <xs:attribute name="begin-chapter" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="optional" />
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="class" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I am using XSD.exe to generate a class that I can deserialize this junk into.

It is generating a begin-line object with a verse-num type below it, and also an array of text, which are split by the html/xml tags inside of .

What I need is an xsd that can be used by XSD.exe to generate a begin-line class that will give me a verse-num type, and then one string property that will contain the rest of the content (including text, i's, b's, footnotes, xml/html).

I did some research and it seems like processContents will do the trick, but I can't figure out where to put it.

When it comes down to it, I want to program against the object created by the XSD.exe like this.

```
var beginLine = new crosswaybiblePassageVerseunitBeginline();
Console.WriteLine((beginLine.Items[0] as crosswaybiblePassageVerseunitBeginlineVersenum).Value);
Console.Write(beginLine.Text);
```

or maybe even...

```
var beginLine = new crosswaybiblePassageVerseunitBeginline();
Console.WriteLine(beginLine.Versenum.Value);
Console.Write(beginLine.Text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to setup the schema such that it'll provide nice output from XSD.exe but you can specify "any number of elements with any name" in the output using a type with the definition:

```
<xs:complexType name="AnyChildren">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute />
</xs:complexType>
```

For example to validate:

```
<Module>
   <Title>Hello World</Title>
   <ProviderType>xyz</ProviderType>
   <Content />
   <MoreContent />
</Module>
```

You could use:

```
<xs:complexType name="Module">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="ProviderType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" nillable="false" />
        <xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute />
</xs:complexType>
```